# Javascript Validation Where String Can Be A Date Or A Specific String

Tags: javascript, validation, date

I'm looking for a way to validate if a date has been entered in dd/mm/yyyy format OR if a specific string has been entered. The string is TBC

So any date would be valid as long as it was dd/mm/yyy and the string TBC would be valid. Anything else would be invalid.

Thanks in advance

Comment: And you also need to validate that the date is an actuall legal date, right? (So no 34/12/2000, and no 31/02/2000 either). And also, what have you tried?

Comment: That would be a nice bonus....

Comment: use a standard date library eg. [`momentjs`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/)

Answer (score 1):

You should use regular expression like this:

```
var datePattern = /^\d{2}[/]\d{2}[/]\d{4}$/
if(value.match(datePattern) || value == "TBC")
   //ok
```

`value` is your input that you want to validate it. Remember you also need to validate `content` of date, in addition to `format`. For example `32/01/2015` or `20/13/2015` have correct format, but have not valid content, so they should not be allowed.